# Weird issues when interpolating string output of fabric command

Tags: python, linux, bash, fabric, string-interpolation

Having trouble understanding how to do something I think should be intuitive with Fabric. I want to capture the stdout that results from a remotely executed command, and then use the result in a subsequent remote call.

However, I'm getting really incomprehensible errors. I sense that there's multiple problems with what I'm doing, but I don't know where to start. Perhaps someone can help me break this apart.

What I have:

```
...
with cd(env.repo):
    abbrev_hash = run('git log -1 --pretty="%h"')
run("rsync -r --exclude '.git/*' %s %s" % (env.repo, abbrev_hash))
...
```

Relevant output:

> [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] run: git log -1 --pretty="%h"
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out: 
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out: c6d4ea0
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out: 
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out: 
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] run: rsync -r --exclude '.git/*' > /home/ubuntu/repos/cookcoc6d4ea0l_2.0-dev
>
> [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out: /bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out: /bin/bash: -c: line 1:`
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out: '
>   [cookcountyjail.recoveredfactory.net] out:
>
> Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
>
> c6d4ea0ed: rsync -r --exclude '.git/*' /home/ubuntu/repos/cookcountyjail_2.0-dev
>
> Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /home/ubuntu/website/2.0/websites && export  PATH=\"\$PATH:\"/home/ubuntu/website/2.0/websites/active\"\" && rsync -r --exclude '.git/*' /home/ubuntu/repos/cookcouc6d4ea0_2.0-dev 
>   "

Comment: By the way, I realize that I could just redirect output by some means or another inside the bash shell, but I'd really like to understand Fabric better.

Answer (score 2):

does this not do what you want ?

```
def t1():
    captured = local('ls -alh')
    print captured
```

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run

> run will return the result of the remote program’s stdout as a single
>   (likely multiline) string. This string will exhibit failed and
>   succeeded boolean attributes specifying whether the command failed or
>   succeeded, and will also include the return code as the return_code
>   attribute. Furthermore, it includes a copy of the requested & actual
>   command strings executed, as .command and .real_command, respectively.

there's also this bit in the `local` docs:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.local

> local is not currently capable of simultaneously printing and
>   capturing output, as run/sudo do. The capture kwarg allows you to
>   switch between printing and capturing as necessary, and defaults to
>   False.
>
> When capture=False, the local subprocess’ stdout and stderr
>   streams are hooked up directly to your terminal, though you may use
>   the global output controls output.stdout and output.stderr to hide one
>   or both if desired. In this mode, the return value’s stdout/stderr
>   values are always empty.
>
> When capture=True, you will not see any
>   output from the subprocess in your terminal, but the return value will
>   contain the captured stdout/stderr.
>
> In either case, as with run and
>   sudo, this return value exhibits the return_code, stderr, failed and
>   succeeded attributes. See run for details.

Comment: `captured = local('ls -alh', capture=True); print captured` does do what I want.

Comment: I don't know, I can't claim the output's not being captured anymore. With the `sudo` command I can capture the output, and print it. Maybe it's some weird string interpolation issue with Fabric. The output doesn't show up when I try to include it as part of a string with regular python sting formatting. I get lots of weird output.

Comment: Sorry for making your answer not so relevant.